# Databricks package com.databricks.spark.xml with encoding issues

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I´m dealing with an encoding problem, almost resolved with the decode/encode of a needed field in a dataframe, as the following example:

df.withColumn("column1", decode(encode("column1", "windows-1252"), "UTF8"))

Getting the values from this [image] to [image], as example.

However in some special cases as, "Á" or "Í", I can't get the expected result:

From this [image] to this [image]

Anyone dealing with the same problems and getting good results with other solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this problem changing the encode to iso-8859-15. And modifying the load of the data also to this encode type as the example below:

```
df = (
spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
.option("encoding", "UTF-8")
.option("charset", "iso-8859-15")
.option("rowTag", "Header")
.load(folder_path)
```